# Create lists of list while creating a map

Tags: elixir

I wrote

```
Enum.reduce(list, map, fn elem, map ->
  key=hd(elem)
  Map.put(map, key, List.wrap(Map.get(map, key)) ++ tl(elem))
end)
```

The list looks like this

```
['B2', ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']],
['B2', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
```

and the desired result looks like

```
B2 => [['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']]
```

The above code does produce this result but it feels like exceptionally ugly.

I feel `Enum.into` could work for a much nicer variant but it seems I can't get hold of the values meanwhile. I have tried

```
Enum.into(list, map, fn [k, v] -> {k, List.wrap(Map.get(map, k)) ++ v} end )
```

but this doesn't produce anything useful. I believe my brain has a hard time coming off the imperative mindset I have used in the last quarter century of coding.

Comment: An example value of `list` and `map` would be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heavily building on Dogbert's answer and this [blog post](https://www.cheeyeo.uk/elixir/protocols/2016/06/26/elixir_protocols_in_action/) I have created my own structure:

```
defmodule MyStruct do
  defstruct []
  def fetch(map, key), do: :maps.find(key, map)
end

defimpl Collectable, for: MyStruct do
  def into(original) do
    {original, fn
      source, {:cont, [k | v ]} -> Map.update(source, k, v, &(&1 ++ v))
      source, :done -> source
    end}
  end
end
```

now I can just do

```
defmodule MyModule
  map=Enum.into(list, %MyStruct{})
end
```

or use the `into: %MyStruct{}` in a comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

While `Enum.reduce/3` is perfectly fine solves the case, I would use `Enum.group_by/2` to clarify an intent. (If and only the performance is not the top priority: `reduce` would be considerably faster.)

```
list = [
  ['A2', ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']],
  ['A2', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
  ['B2', ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']],
  ['B2', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
] # thanks @Dogbert for the input

list
|> Enum.group_by(&Kernel.hd/1)
|> Enum.into(%{}, fn {k, e} ->
  {k, Enum.map(e, &List.last/1)}
end)

# %{'A2' => [['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
#   'B2' => [['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `Enum.reduce/3` as well, but instead of `Map.put/3` + `List.wrap/1`, I'd use `Map.update/4` and instead of `hd/1` and `tl/1` some pattern matching.

```
list = [
  ['A2', ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']],
  ['A2', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
  ['B2', ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']],
  ['B2', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
]

list
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn [k | v], acc ->
  Map.update(acc, k, v, &(&1 ++ v))
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
%{'A2' => [['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
  'B2' => [['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']]}
```

Comment: I missed the initial value on `Map.update` -- I presumed `update` just updates.` &(&1 ++ v) ` is just a shorthand for `fn x -> x ++v end` if I gather correctly.